# typeof(_Default) Error using Log4Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I am working on a C# MVC Project and I need some auditory, so I installed Log4net on the project, and followed this tutorial here

http://kaizen-force.com/2015/03/24/log4net-c-visual-studio-2013/

And When I use this line of code

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(_Default));
```

I get this error

```
Error   2   The type or namespace name '_Default' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  D:\PC\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SSMS-2.0.1\SSMS-2.0.1\Controllers\UsuariosXesController.cs    20  72  SSMS_2._0._1
```

Did I miss something? How can I made this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You'll note](https://kaizentic.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/pantalla_6.jpg) that in the tutorial he's created a class called `_Default`, and this `log` field is a static field inside that class. If you have a differently-named class, then you need to change the name inside of `typeof()`.

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(UsuariosXesController));
```